# search for a substring which returns true if it is at the end

Tags: php, substring

I would like to search for a substring in php so that it will be at the end of the given string.
Eg
on string 'abd def' if I search for def it would be at the end, so return true. But if I search for abd it will return false since it is not at the end.

Is it possible?

Comment: `Is it possible?` YES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming whole words:

```
$match = 'def';
$words = explode(' ', 'abd def');

if (array_pop($words) == $match) {
  ...
}
```

Or using a regex:

```
if (preg_match('/def$/', 'abd def')) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) for this:

```
$str = 'abd def';
$result = (preg_match("/def$/", $str) === 1);
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to do it which does not require splitting by a separator or regular expressions. This tests whether the last `x` characters equal the test string, where `x` equals the length of the test string:

```
$string = "abcdef";
$test = "def";

if(substr($string, -(strlen($test))) === $test)
{
    /* logic here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer should be fully robust regardless of full words or anything else

```
$match = 'def';
$words = 'abd def';

$location = strrpos($words, $match); // Find the rightmost location of $match
$matchlength = strlen($match);       // How long is $match

/* If the rightmost location + the length of what's being matched
 * is equal to the length of what's being searched,
 * then it's at the end of the string
 */
if ($location + $matchlength == strlen($words)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look [strrchr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php) function. Try like this

```
$word   = 'abcdef';
$niddle = 'def';
if (strrchr($word, $niddle) == $niddle) {
    echo 'true';
} else {
    echo 'false';
}
```